# Hardware solution for small IT company

Tags: networking, hardware

I'm starting up a small programming company for web development soon, so I have couple of questions and dilemmas in my mind.

First of all should I go for standalone machines for each programmer or should i go for a server and thin clients? Please give me some input on solution that you are advising me to go for. 
I'm very interested in the server+thin combination and would like to know what kind of server should i get and what clients? The company will have 5 employees and probably expand in an year or two to 10 or more people. 
What software to use on the server if that is a good solution?

Thanks for your answers and thoughts in advance!

Comment: This is probably better suited for a forum like [Spiceworks](http://community.spiceworks.com/welcome).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the decisions that will shape your company, your company culture, how your employees work, how they feel about work, how productive they are, how your development and deployment processes work - other people can't really answer them for you.

Thin clients have the advantage of cost compared to laptops or desktops, but they are slower to use (all the screen drawing has to go over a network), and they make the server a single point of failure so you might want to buy a better server to cope with that risk. This will make using and testing with web browsers feel different to how your customers will see the site.

If you're developing with heavier software such as Visual Studio, or NetBeans+Java, or with multiple copies of a database for testing, that will matter.

If you need the developers to be able to work remotely, that matters.

If you need the developers to be designers working on logos in drawing programs, that matters.

If you need developers to run virtual machines so they can test the site from Windows 7 and Mac OS X and Android, that will matter.

I would consider starting from "what kind of websites are we developing, for what platforms and what customers?" and then go to "what kind of developers will be making these sites, and what are their workflows and processes like?" and then go to "what hardware and software do we need to make this work well?".

Starting with the hardware and software first is backwards - gather requirements first, then choose what to spend money on to handle the requirements.